# how to autoincrement the default value in texbox

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to autoincrement default value in text box assuming data type as text without having to create table? i needed this to happen when form loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done when a form is opened, so you would need to call this Sub (located in a Module) to open the form:

```
Sub ChangeDefaultValue()
  DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form1"
  DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", acDesign, , , , acHidden
  Dim f As Form
  Set f = Forms("Form1")
  Dim dv As Integer
  dv = f.Controls!Text0.DefaultValue
  f.Controls!Text0.DefaultValue = dv + 1
  DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form1", acSaveYes
  DoCmd.OpenForm ("Form1")
End Sub
```

You will need to change the form name "Form1" and TextBox name "Text0" to your names.

Comment: I am getting run time error 2135 THis property is read only cant be set

Comment: I guess I am not clear on exactly what you want to do. Do you want to permanently increment the TextBox field's DefaultValue every time you load the Form? Also is the TextBox bound to a table or a query?

Comment: yes, i wanted  to permanently increment the TextBox field's DefaultValue every time you load the Form. Text box is unbounded.

Comment: That code works perfect fine for me.  I have it loaded under a button click event on a menu form